# Alternative for mysql Events (not Cronjob)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

5 minutes after a specific user action occurred, I need to change some data in my database. Till now I have programmed on my homeserver and I have used mysql Events in order to achieve this, which worked perfectly. But my current provider where I now host my website restricts the use of mysql Events.

Now I have to come up with an alternative for mysql Events.

I thought about executing a php script that changes the data in the background by using `exec("php script.php &> /dev/null &")`, which actually works (at least on my homeserver) but which is also restricted by my provider.

Now I'm really out of ideas and need your help - how can I do the trick?

Thank you!

Christof

EDIT:
Cronjobs don't do the trick in my case, since I have to execute the script only if the specific user action has occurred.

Comment: Can you not get a cronjob to 1. Check if user action was done 2. Perform whatever function

Comment: Or make the User Action create a row in a Queue table, then get the cron to check the queue table for a list of things to do, removeing them when its done the whatever processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, I could do this but I would have to execute the CronJob at least every minute since it has to be quite precise 5 minutes, which would cause a lot of server traffic.

Comment: It is like namecheap or all the rest: `According to our Acceptable Use Policy, running cron jobs with intervals of less than 15 minutes or setting up more than 5 simultaneous cron jobs is prohibited. ` There is good reason it is disallowed. Ok, your alternatives are something like aws ec2 and claw back your G given right to do this (also their right to charge you 10 to 40 a month). Or stay where you are and have an external agent do it for you (like java, c#, python) etc

Comment: @Drew How could I solve my problem using an external agent?

Comment: Let me just write up an answer. It is highly opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the following as you have `PHP` tagged here.

Create an account with aws ec2 and start with their [Free-Tier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-free-tier.html) for one year. This will allow the creation of an AMI (Amazon Machine Instance) of your choosing. Typically Linux, but can be a Microsoft variant. Tweak it and [save](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816549) it. Linux is the normal choice due to limited resources (memory) granted. It will be a Small Instance [Type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) for free for 1 year.

Note I have no affiliation with AMZN. It could just as easily be something from Azure/Microsoft or Google. However, I have used ec2 since 2008 and a reasonable person would come to the conclusion that they are several years ahead of their competition. Which might suggest why Openshift and others just punted and layer on top of them anyway. One should read up on IaaS vs PaaS to know that there are complexities in setting up an IaaS solution. It is not something that someone non-technical ought to have recommended to them.

On the PaaS side, I would go with Openshift. There is a lot to be said for those.

I shoot for IaaS due to wanting anything installed on the virtual server as well as my code to listen on any ports and the choice of protocols.

If one then has an ec2 or equivalent virtual server, one is able to harness the programming language of their choice (an `agent` running in java, c#, python, etc) for a timer to make a call to your shared-host environment PHP (including authentication on https) to trigger the shared host `event-like` mechanism. Or, better yet, have your mysql instance running on ec2 or RDS.

The reason one should consider the above includes

- Cutting one's teeth on a platform likely to be used later
- It beats power failures for the old laptop in your closet you could use otherwise
- You might end up on the cloud and want these `agents` to perform *Other Tasks*
- By getting off of shared-hosts you do not suffer from cron or event restrictions.

As for *Other Tasks* you will find that Events have limitations. One of the biggest is the inability to call `LOAD DATA INFILE` from stored programs. I use agents for that. Your agents can start on o/s startup.

After a trial one can end up using micro instances if still on shared hosts yet integrating with a more powerful virtual server. I estimate it at $12/month, perhaps cheaper, for agents to be running in the cloud 24/7, pointing and doing whatever. Less powerful instance types, but possible. I cannot speak to the power or lack thereof with `nano` instance types.

Note that an agent can have embedded mysql client libraries (the program does a Using or Import and is a mysql client program). In this case it does direct connects to port 3306. This might work fine for an AWS-only solution, but exposing the db server to the internet is a security risk. If in doubt, one ought to look at the General Query log to see the attacks that mount. The Best Practice is to shield your DB Server from this as hidden behind the firewall. This is why an API like those thru PHP are highly preferred. So, there is nothing keeping you from writing a 100 line agent that does an authenticated `POST` via `https` to your shared-host `PHP` and you take it from there.

Other options include creating SSH Tunnels. But I digress.

Comment: Wow, @Drew ! Thank you very, very much for explaining it to me that precise. I think that's a pretty creative way for doing this and you would have actually convinced me but it's certainly a lot of work. So, wouldn't it be easier to host my whole website on an virtual server, through which I'm able to use mysql events? Whereas I nevertheless could use your option with the external agent, because I somehow like this one ... What do you think?

Comment: This is an example of a hybrid mixture moving toward complete control. Often people can't uproot their current host and suffer DNS Propagation issues. Such as, we will be up in 12 hours. One has to remember too that it has to be secure to avoid as much tomfoolery from others, even if DoS attacks. For instance, it cannot be as simple as calling a `doIt.php` file, unsecure, in the root of your shared host acct. A `nano` instance on AWS is $4 a month. Doesn't rock anyone's world and little change is required.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, the best way to handle this sort of suspense-file database item is to use an effective-time strategy.  The best thing about this strategy is this: it doesn't depend on the timing accuracy of your events, or cronjobs, or whatever.

You didn't say what needs to happen to your data five minutes after the user action, so I'll have to guess.

Suppose the operation is to remove a row from `table_a` and insert a row into `table_b`.   In that case, you'd add a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column `effective_until` to `table_a` and another column `effective_after` to `table_b`.

When the user action occurs, you do something like

```
 UPDATE table_a 
    SET effective_until = NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
  WHERE id='whatever';
```

and

```
 INSERT INTO table_b  (id, data, effective_after)
               VALUES (whatever, whatelse, NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

Then, later, whenever you *use* `table_a` you say

```
 SELECT ... FROM table_a WHERE (effective_until <= NOW() OR effective_until IS NULL) ;
```

and when you use `table_b` you say

```
 SELECT ... FROM table_a WHERE effective_after > NOW();
```

Once a day, or once a week, or whatever, you can purge the dead stuff from `table_a` with something like this.

```
  DELETE FROM table_a WHERE effective_until <= NOW();
```

The trick is to mark your rows with timestamps, instead of relying on precisely timed operations. Much more robust and reliable. Resilient when the cronjobs fail for a whole weekend. Also, compatible with cheap hosting services and uncooperative dbas, both of which the world has an abundance.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'd need the mysql events for two different operations:  1. 5 minutes after the action has occurred, I need to change data from '0' to '1', which I could (quite easily) do by using, saving and comparing timestamps, just as you suggested to do. But there's a second usage:  2. I need to change data in my database at a specific time and date which I will have set a few weeks before. So, for instance, in two weeks I would set 10 different mysql events which will fire on different days the week later. How would you suggest doing this using your solution?