# Trouble installing MySQL on Amazon Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install MySQL on my Amazon Linux instance following these set of commands:

**(Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025524/how-to-install-mysql-5-7-on-amazon-ec2)):**

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
yum remove mysql55 mysql55-common mysql55-libs mysql55-server
yum install mysql-community-server
service mysqld restart
mysql_upgrade -p
```

However, when I run:

```
service mysqld restart
```

I get the following error message:

[image]

Running the same command prefixed with sudo gets the following error message:

[image]

And then running:

```
mysql_upgrade -p
```

Produces the following error message:

[image]

A little bit lost on how to tackle this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the root user to try the above operation.
If permission is still denied, then you need to focus on SELinux and AppArmor.